# Ошибка при правильных отступах в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, отступы

Есть веб приложение на flask, есть файл forms.py, при запуске ругается на 18 строку ( def validate_birthDate(self, birthDate):), а именно IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level, в vs code последний символ (:) помечается аналогичной ошибкой. Пробовал заново задавать табуляцию по образцу (есть похожий файл в другом проекте, там ошибок не возникает)

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, DateField, SelectField, SelectMultipleField,TextAreaField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, EqualTo, Length, Email, ValidationError
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

import re
import connectDB

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    fullName = StringField('ФИО', validators = [DataRequired('Это обязательное поле'), Length(min = 8, max = 30, message = 'Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    email = StringField('Электронная почта', validators = [DataRequired('Это обязательное поле'), Email(message="Некорректный почтовый адрес"), Length(min = 8, max = 40, message = 'Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    password = PasswordField('Пароль', validators=[DataRequired(message="Это обязательное поле"), Length(min=6, max=32, message='Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    password2 = PasswordField('Повторите пароль', validators=[DataRequired(message="Это обязательное поле"), EqualTo('password', message='Пароли должны совпадать')])
    birthDate = DateField('Дата рождения (формат: ДД.ММ.ГГГГ)', format = "%d.%m.%Y",validators=[DataRequired(message="Это обязательное поле")])
    submit = SubmitField('Регистрация')

    def validate_birthDate(self, birthDate):
            today = date.today()
        if (birthDate.data < today - timedelta(days=100*365)) or (birthDate.data > today - timedelta(days=7*365)):
            raise ValidationError('Недопустимая дата рождения')
    def validate_fullName(self, fullName):
        if not re.match('^[а-яА-Я\'\- ]*$', fullName.data):
            raise ValidationError('Допускается только кириллица')     
    def validate_email(self, email):
        conn = connectDB.get_connection()
        curs = conn.cursor()
        sql = "select * from users where email = %s;"
        curs.execute(sql, (email.data,))
        result = curs.fetchone()
        conn.close()
        if result is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Этот email уже зарегестрирован!')
   
   
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Электронная почта', validators = [DataRequired('Это обязательное поле'), Email(message="Некорректный почтовый адрес"), Length(min = 8, max = 40, message = 'Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    password = PasswordField('Пароль', validators=[DataRequired(message="Это обязательное поле"), Length(min=6, max=32, message='Длина должна быть между %(min)d и %(max)d символами')])
    rememberMe = BooleanField('Запомнить меня')
    submit = SubmitField('Вход')
```

Comment: я смотрю в эту функцию и вижу неправильные отступы. Странно, что вы этого не видите.

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate_birthDate(self, birthDate):
        today = date.today()
    if (birthDate.data < today - timedelta(days=100*365)) or (birthDate.data > today - timedelta(days=7*365)):
        raise ValidationError('Недопустимая дата рождения')
```

знаменита на

```
def validate_birthDate(self, birthDate):
    today = date.today()
    if (birthDate.data < today - timedelta(days=100*365)) or (birthDate.data > today - timedelta(days=7*365)):
        raise ValidationError('Недопустимая дата рождения')
```

Comment: Не сработало, сначала вроде выскочила другая ошибка, но после ее фикса эта появилась снова